# Display whole word from line

Tags: linux, string, grep, command-line-interface, unique

I wanted to display only unique words as output. How to define grep expression ?

`strings file.txt |grep (filter to display only whole words) | unique`

Comment: can you show some example data of your file.txt? otherwise we cannot provide correct answer.

Comment: strings command will extract all string char, I'm piping the result to grep command,where I wanted to get result of whole word only[that is., if a line contains more space, words between space should be display]. Text file is too large, so I can't share. Hope it explains..!

Comment: Paste some data please. E.g. `foo bar blah` and `foo, blah, bar!` and `foo! bar. blah!` are different. and your problem is not only on grep part, `uniq` works only for sorted file. so, again, paste input data examples, and also the expected output!

Comment: Please refer my previous comment for sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file.txt | sed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g' | sort -u
```

Comment: cat will display not string char too. I'm interested only in strings currently. So I replaced your cat with strings command. The sed display line with space. I need to break the line if it got space and display into whole world. Example line "Hello world, basic" - expected result:Hello, world,, basic

Comment: Useless use of `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to translate "whitespace" into newlines:

```
strings file.txt | tr '[:blank:]' '\n' | sort -u
```

Comment: Yes I need to translate whitespace or tab into newlines. I've tried your command. But it still displays whitespace in some line of output

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
s="sample word sample word samples"
echo "$s" |grep -oE "\b\w+\b"|sort -u
```

Output:

```
sample
samples
word
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm expecting. How can we use the same method in python?

Comment: @jOSe like running this code with subprocess or os.system()?